# Easiest way to create an rtf file in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, rtf

I have tried using,

```
with open(myfile.rtf, 'a') as file:
    file.write("{\rtf1\ansi{\fonttbl\f0\fswiss Helvetica;}\f0\pard")
    file.write(my_String_here)
    file.write("\par}")
```

I have briefly looked at PyRTF but wasn't able to find an example that works with Python3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is probably that `\r` and similar characters are treated as escape characters. Use raw strigns instead, eg `write(r'{\rtf1....')`